# Cutting text to specific length preserving the words

Tags: c#, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2012, clr

I have the following text:

> Test some text. Now here is some new realylonglonglong text

And I need to cut it to 50 characters but without cutting the words. So, the desire result is:

> Test some text. Now here is some new ...

I am looking only for solution using regular expression replace. The following regular expression:

```
^.{0,50}(?= |$)
```

matches:

> Test some text. Now here is some new

but I failed transforming it for use in replace function.

---

In my real case I have SQL CLR function called `[dbo].[RegexReplace]` and I am calling it like this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[RegexReplace](@TEST, '^.{0,50}(?= |$)', '...')
```

Its C# definition is:

```
        public static string Replace(SqlString sqlInput, SqlString sqlPattern, SqlString sqlReplacement)
        {
            string input = (sqlInput.IsNull) ? string.Empty : sqlInput.Value;
            string pattern = (sqlPattern.IsNull) ? string.Empty : sqlPattern.Value;
            string replacement = (sqlReplacement.IsNull) ? string.Empty : sqlReplacement.Value;
            return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
        }
```

That's why I want to to this with regular expression replace function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex you want:

```
string result = Regex.Replace("Test some text. Now here is some new realylonglonglong text", "(?=.{50,})(^.{0,50}) .*", "$1...");
```

so look for `^(?=.{50,})(.{0,50}) .*` and replace it with `$1...`

Explanation... You are looking for texts that are AT LEAST 50 characters long, because shorter texts don't need shortening, so `(?=.{50,})` (but note that this won't capture anything). Then you look for the first 0...50 characters (`.{0,50}`) followed by a space , followed by anything else `.*`. You'll replace all of this with the first 0...50 characters (`$1`) followed by `...`

I need the `(?=.{50,})` because otherwise the regex would replace `Test test` with `Test...`, replacing from the first space.

Comment: If you run this regex against "Test some text. Now here is some new really extremely very long text", it will truncate the word "extremely".  Not sure if this is what the OP was going for, but looks like they've accepted the answer.